# Entity framework migrations throws exception when using extension method for fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 6, Code-First with Fluent-API.

I have the following extension method to set the primary key on my entities:

```
public static class ConfigurationExtensions
{
    public static void HasPrimaryKey<TEntityType>(this EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntityType> configuration)
        where TEntityType : class, IEntity
    {
        configuration
            .HasKey(m => m.Id)
            .Property(t => t.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    }
}
```

with every Code-First Entity implementing the following simple interface:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int Id { get; }
}
```

Now suppose I have the following Entity:

```
public class MyEntity : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

which I'm configuring with Fluent-API in my `DbContext`

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MyEntityConfiguration());
}
```

with the configuration class for the entity:

```
public class MyEntityConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<MyEntity>
{
    public MyEntityConfiguration()
    {
        this.HasPrimaryKey()
    }
}
```

Oddly when I execute `Add-Migration` in the *Package Manager Console* I get the following exception:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The property 'Id' cannot be used as a key property on the entity 'MyEntity' because the property type is not a valid key type. Only scalar types, string and byte[] are supported key types.
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.EntityTypeConfiguration.Key(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, Nullable`1 overridableConfigurationParts)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.EntityTypeConfiguration.Key(IEnumerable`1 keyProperties)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.EntityTypeConfiguration`1.HasKey[TKey](Expression`1 keyExpression)
   at ConfigurationExtensions.HasPrimaryKey[TEntityType](EntityTypeConfiguration`1 configuration) in C:\path\ConfigurationExtensions.cs
```

It is odd because when I refactor the code in the extension method back into the constructor, like this:

```
public class MyEntityConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<MyEntity>
{
    public MyEntityConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(m => m.Id)
        .Property(t => t.Id)
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    }
}
```

then, the exception is not thrown by the framework and everything works as expected. Why? Framework bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception message is misleading. The actual issue is quite trivial. EF supports only properties that have a property setter.

Since the expression `m => m.Id` in your generic extension method binds to the `Id` property of the `IEntity` interface, which has no setter (in contrast with the implementing class), EF does not consider it a valid property and throws the exception with the misleading message about property type.

To fix it, simply define setter for the `Id` property inside the interface:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}
```

It can also be resolved by building the lambda expression manually using the `Expression` class methods, but I think modifying the interface is easier :) But here it is for completeness and in case you don't want to break your interface design:

```
public static class ConfigurationExtensions
{
    public static void HasPrimaryKey<TEntityType>(this EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntityType> configuration)
        where TEntityType : class, IEntity
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntityType), "m");
        var keyProperty = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntityType, int>>(Expression.Property(parameter, nameof(IEntity.Id)), parameter);
        configuration
            .HasKey(keyProperty)
            .Property(keyProperty)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm accepting this answer since it clarifies why Entity Framework is throwing the exception. Obviously the `IEntity` interface defines a contract within the application's architecture and design, thus changing this would break the initial design of that architecture. I'd rather have a [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) design rather than a generic extension method which sole purpose is to act as a helper method to make code a little bit more [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: Also a funny thing to note is that a company like Microsoft is throwing a misleading exception like this and thus violating their own rules/guidelines on [Framework Design Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042(v=vs.110).aspx) for exceptions.